# Nesting transactions and honoring rollbacks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In general, I just want to be able to do this:

```
begin transaction
begin transaction
select 'x'
rollback
rollback
```

The reason is, I have a stored proc with code like this:

```
begin transaction

--Do stuff

If(problem)
begin 
    rollback
end else begin
    commit
end
```

It works just like I want it to, but I want to test it by doing this:

```
begin transaction
exec MyStoredProc
rollback
```

When the stored proc executes a rollback it seems to close both transactions, and then my rollback outside the stored proc fails.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't really have nested transactions. Sure you can nest them in code - but in the end, there's always just one transaction, and if you roll the one back, all the outerwards "nested" ones are rolled back, too. See [SQL Server DBA myths 26 of 30 - nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-(2630)-nested-transactions-are-real.aspx) for a lot more info on ths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an autonomous transaction in SQL Server. Nesting transactions serves to increase `@@TRANCOUNT`, but that's about it. As @marc_s suggested in his comment, `ROLLBACK` does not apply solely to the current transaction scope/level, it applies to the whole thing.

This request was rejected in 2008:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/324569/add-support-for-true-nested-transactions

However, this request is still active - so maybe there is hope:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/296870/add-support-for-autonomous-transactions

As for your outer rollback failing, you can always check for this first instead of doing it blindly, e.g.:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: ah, this work fine because

begin transaction
begin transaction
delete from MyTable
commit
rollback

Doesn't actually delete any records.  based on how rollback behaved I expected it to commit both transaction then throw an error.